# How to debug "mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given"?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and it is showing

> "warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_result, boolean given"

My Code is :

```
<?php
include_once 'Conn.php';
 $qry="select * from sumit";
  $res=  mysqli_query($GLOBALS['link'],$qry);
echo '<table border="5">';
echo '<tr><th>Empno</th><th>Name</th><th>Adress</th><th>Salary</th></tr>';

while($r= mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {
        echo "<tr><td>$r[0]</td><td>$r[1]</td><td>$r[2]</td><td>$r[3]</td></tr>";
    }  
    echo '</table>';
```

Comment: can you show the contents of `conn.php`

Comment: use **mysqli_error($con)**

Comment: conn.php<?php
$host="localhost";
$uname="root";
$pwd=""; 
$link=  mysqli_connect($host, $uname, $pwd,"fresh");
?>

Comment: Does the database "fresh" and table "sumit" exists?

Comment: I tried using this method of creating the connection object and running a query and that was fine so, as @ThinkDifferent suggested, can you confirm that the table does exist and that the db is correct.

Comment: `mysqli_query` returns false: _Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object._ Catch the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array()/mysql\_fetch\_assoc()/mysql\_fetch\_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource or mysqli\_result, boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-mysql-fetch-assoc-mysql-fetch-row-expects-parameter-1-to)

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally - though this doesn't solve your problem it might help when it comes to accessing records. If you use `mysqli_fetch_object` it makes it much easier to retrieve records imho. As an example:

```
include 'conn.php';
$con=$GLOBALS['link'];

if( is_object( $con ) ){
    $sql='select * from `city` limit 10';
    $res=mysqli_query( $con, $sql );

    if( $res ){
        while( $rs = mysqli_fetch_object( $res ) ) echo '<div>'.$rs->Name. ' '.$rs->CountryCode.' '.$rs->District.' '.$rs->Population.'</div>';
    }
    mysqli_free_result( $res );
    mysqli_close( $con );
    $con=null;
}
```